# Is there a nice way to script network related tests using UIAutomation on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, instruments, ui-automation

I'm looking for a way to test some network connectivity scenarios using UIAutomation (e.g. making sure the right messages are shown to the user for various connectivity scenarios).  Has anyone come across a way to turn off the network on an iOS device (e.g. enable Airplane mode) in a scriptable way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. After scouring the internet for long time I came to the conclusion that this cannot be done using UIAutomation class. You need to either do this manually or use some other way such as writing a piece of objective-c code that programatically turns off the wifi/network or use some other automation tool to write a script that turns on/off the netwrok. You can then run/call the script/code from instruments using performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout function. Although I could't implement this myself. If anyone has a better solution please share!

Comment: `performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout` executes tasks on the host (your mac), not the device being tested. You're not going to alter the device's network settings that way.

Answer (score 0):

actually you might be able to if you are connecting to the host machine's wireless and disable it via command line but i haven't tested it out yet.

Comment: This post might be better as a comment on the original question... :)